# Which form is correct with pursue?

Tags: grammar, phrases, business-language

I am not sure about which of the following forms would be correct:

- I was pursuing my passions studying CS at University
- I was pursuing my passions **by** studying CS at University
- I was pursuing my passions **when**/**while** studying CS at University

What I would like to say is: I was very passionate about something so it was a obvious next step that I went studying CS (and then I have received my MSc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*None of them are correct.* From your explanation it feels like you have already completed your course, therefore the correct alternative is:

> **I pursued my passion by studying CS at the University.**

The task is finished and you received the degree, hence **you have to use simple past** i.e. **'I pursued'** *instead of 'was pursuing' because 'was pursuing' indicates that you are still pursuing the degree from some point in the past.*

**You pursued a single passion i.e. of studying CS** and therefore instead of writing 'passions', **write it's singular form i.e. 'passion'.**

**If you use 'while' then it will change the meaning of the sentence.**

*For example: "I pursued my passion while studying CS at the University." means that 'You pursued a different thing (which is your passion) while studying CS in addition (i.e. CS isn't your passion).'*

Also, **'when' has no significance in this context.**

*Hope, this helped :)*

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot :).